# Halcon - Affine transformation for NCC model matching with scale down image using image pyramid

Tags: halcon

Hi i have an issue with affine transformation of a NCC model matching (NumLevel 4, because i have a large image).

I have created a NCC model in scale down image pyramid (GenGaussPyramid)
Then find NCC model in the scale down image.

Anyone know how to affine transfer the found model region back to original image (NumLevel 1)?

Comment: Hi, how large is the image? did you try Halcon XL? It  can handle images larger than 32768 x 32768

Comment: Yes, i'm using HalconXL. The issue is creating and searching for model will take very long time.

Comment: Let’s suppose that for the function gen_gauss_pyramid you used scale =0.5.
An original image 640 x 480 to the 4th level is to 80 x 60 pixels. If you find the object in the image 80 x 60 and you made a position error of 1 pixel and then you go directly in the original image you'll find the object with a position error of 8 pixels.

Comment: The search algorithm when works with pyramid images it searches the object to the 4th level and when it found it, it will search in the 3rd level in a near position found in the 4th level. After, when it will find the object in the 3rd level, it will search in the 2nd level in a near position found in the 3rd level. This until the 1st level.  So it will search 4 times the object (in the levels 1 to 3 it will search the object with a reduced domain). In this case, the error will be very low.
So are you sure you‘d like to pass from the 4th level directly to the 1st level?

Comment: i understand exactly what you mean. I have to skip the auto search algorithm of different level. The reason is because ROI/reduce domain is still too large for teaching and searching. It takes really long time. So what i do is teaches and searches all jump into a scale down image to speed up the teaching and searching.

Comment: And my issue now is like what you described. my results of affine trans region back to original image has position error by many pixels due to high num level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did you a small demo.
The core is where it's written reverse affine transformation.

Here the code

```
* test image with the pattern (circle)
gen_image_const (EmptyImage, 'byte', 640, 480)
OriginalRow :=240
OriginalColumn  := 400
OriginalRadius := 8
gen_circle (Circle, OriginalRow ,OriginalColumn, OriginalRadius)
gen_circle_contour_xld (CircleXLD, OriginalRow, OriginalColumn, OriginalRadius, 0, 6.28318, 'positive', 0.1)
paint_xld (CircleXLD, EmptyImage, OriginalTestImage, 255)

dev_display (OriginalTestImage)
dev_set_draw ('margin')
dev_set_color ('blue')
dev_display (CircleXLD)
stop()

* creation of pyramid image
Scale := 0.5
gen_gauss_pyramid (OriginalTestImage, ImagePyramid, 'weighted', Scale)

LevelIndex := 4
select_obj (ImagePyramid, Level, LevelIndex )

* ideal found circle
LevelScale := pow(Scale,LevelIndex-1)
hom_mat2d_identity (HomMat2DIdentity)
hom_mat2d_translate (HomMat2DIdentity, OriginalRow*LevelScale -OriginalRow, OriginalColumn*LevelScale - OriginalColumn, HomMat2DTranslate)
hom_mat2d_scale (HomMat2DTranslate, LevelScale, LevelScale, OriginalRow*LevelScale+0.5, OriginalColumn*LevelScale+0.5, HomMat2DScale)
affine_trans_contour_xld (CircleXLD, IdealFoundCircleXLD, HomMat2DScale)

* simulation of searching in the 4th level
threshold_sub_pix (Level, Border, 128)
area_center_xld (Border, Area, FoundRow, FoundColumn, _)
FoundRadius:= sqrt(Area/3.14)
gen_circle_contour_xld (FoundCircleXLD, FoundRow, FoundColumn, FoundRadius, 0, 6.28318, 'positive', 0.1)

dev_display (Level)
dev_set_draw ('margin')
dev_set_color ('green')
dev_display (IdealFoundCircleXLD)
dev_set_color ('red')
dev_display (FoundCircleXLD)
stop()

* reverse affine transformation
ReverseLevelScale := pow(1/Scale,LevelIndex-1)
hom_mat2d_identity (HomMat2DIdentity)
hom_mat2d_translate (HomMat2DIdentity, FoundRow*ReverseLevelScale -FoundRow, FoundColumn*ReverseLevelScale - FoundColumn, HomMat2DTranslate)
hom_mat2d_scale (HomMat2DTranslate, ReverseLevelScale, ReverseLevelScale, FoundRow*ReverseLevelScale+0.5, FoundColumn*ReverseLevelScale+0.5, HomMat2DScale)

affine_trans_contour_xld (IdealFoundCircleXLD, ReverseIdealFoundCircleXLD, HomMat2DScale)
affine_trans_contour_xld (FoundCircleXLD, ReverseFoundCircleXLD, HomMat2DScale)

dev_display (OriginalTestImage)
dev_set_draw ('margin')
dev_set_color ('blue')
dev_display (CircleXLD)
dev_set_color ('green')
dev_display (ReverseIdealFoundCircleXLD)
dev_set_color ('red')
dev_display (ReverseFoundCircleXLD)
stop()
```